# Adding changing text onclick to JavaScript gallery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, onclick

I'm trying to set up a simple gallery with thumbnails and a main content section. When a thumbnail is clicked, I would like a larger version of the image along with text to display in the main content section. I've got the code for the images down, but can't figure out how to add text on each click. I haven't started doing any styling yet, but the basic code is below. Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

JavaScript:

```
    var mainImg = document.getElementById('Main');

    document.getElementById('One').onclick = function() {
            mainImg.src = 'http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0176/5914/files/Kaylee_Radzyminski.jpg?7297';


     mainImg.innerHTML = imagetitle;

      //alert('one clicked');
    };
    document.getElementById('Two').onclick = function() {
            mainImg.src = 'http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0176/5914/files/Mason_Hunter_Thornal.jpg?7297';
      mainImg.innerHTML = 'imagetitle';      

      //alert('two clicked');
    };

      document.getElementById('Three').onclick = function() {
            mainImg.src = 'http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0176/5914/files/Joseph_Nunez_4afb23ac-d71e-42a0-9366-ac78d65deaf4.jpg?7297';
            //alert('two clicked');
    };
```

CSS:

```
#One, #Two, #Three {
width:100px;
opacity: .5; /* css standard */
filter: alpha(opacity=50); /* internet explorer */
}

#One:hover, #Two:hover, #Three:hover {
width:100px;
opacity: 1; /* css standard */
filter: alpha(opacity=100); /* internet explorer */
}
```

HTML:

```
<img id="Main" src="http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0176/5914/files/Kaylee_Radzyminski.jpg?7297" alt="" />


<img id="One" src="http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0176/5914/files/Kaylee_Radzyminski.jpg?7297" alt="" />
<img id="Two" src="http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0176/5914/files/Mason_Hunter_Thornal.jpg?7297" alt="" />
<img id="Three" src="http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0176/5914/files/Joseph_Nunez_4afb23ac-d71e-42a0-9366-ac78d65deaf4.jpg?7297" alt="" />
```

http://jsfiddle.net/f9B8H/72/

Comment: Are you okay with using jQuery, because it will be a lot faster for me to cook something up for you in jQuery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's clean this up a bit.

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
    <img id="Main" src="http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0176/5914/files/Kaylee_Radzyminski.jpg?7297" alt="" />
    <p id="caption"></p>
</div>
<img id="One" src="http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0176/5914/files/Kaylee_Radzyminski.jpg?7297" alt="I'm a soldier" />
<img id="Two" src="http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0176/5914/files/Mason_Hunter_Thornal.jpg?7297" alt="My family" />
<img id="Three" src="http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0176/5914/files/Joseph_Nunez_4afb23ac-d71e-42a0-9366-ac78d65deaf4.jpg?7297" alt="Dad" />
```

Notice how I've stored the caption in the alt attribute. A data attribute could also work.

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
function displayImage() {
    var mainImg = document.getElementById('Main');
    var caption = document.getElementById('caption');
    mainImg.src = this.src;
    caption.innerHTML = this.alt;
}

document.getElementById('One').onclick = displayImage;
document.getElementById('Two').onclick = displayImage;
document.getElementById('Three').onclick = displayImage;
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/g2hY4/

The simplified function works so well because you are using the same image for thumbnail as main image. If you didn't do that, we could store the big image address in a data attribute also.

Here's one way to load the first caption when the page loads. Put it after the code I've already shown you:

```
displayImage.call(document.getElementById('One') );
```

You can read about `call`  [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call). In a nutshell, it redefines the value of `this` in the `displayImage` function.

[New fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DEX7z/2/)

Something to think about is where you want the caption and how it's styled can be set in CSS. I've left that to you also. Absolute positioning will work if the positioning of #container is set to relative.

Comment: Thank you Jeffman! If I wanted to load the first caption when the page loads, what would you suggest assuming I stick with the code you've provided.

Comment: Thanks again! One more question. I'd like to change the Thumbnail Opacity to 1 while the Thumbnail is active (as is the case one you hover over the thumbnail). I have tried adding some CSS #One:active, #Two:active, etc... but that doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

I'd call the onclick from the image itself instead of adding the onclick via JS to the image.
You're doubling your work.

Where do you want the text to be displayed?
If it has to be displayed on top of the image, you'll have to make the image a background-image of a div or so.
If the text has to be above/under the image, place a span above/under the image and give it an ID.

**Working with a span**

JS:

```
function showBig(srcBig, title) {
    var mainImg = document.getElementById('MainImg');
    var mainText = document.getElementById('MainText');
    mainImg.src = srcBig;
    mainImg.title = title;
    mainText.innerHTML = title;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="main">
    <span id="MainText">Title will come here</span>
    <img src="Default Img" alt="Big img's will come here" />
</div>

<img src="URL of thumbnail (e.g. smaller version)" alt="" onClick="showBig('URL of big version', 'Title')" />
```

**Working with BG-image**

JS:

```
function showBig(srcBig, title) {
    var mainDiv = document.getElementById('MainDiv');
    MainDiv.style.backgroundImage = srcBig;
    MainDiv.innerHTML = title;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="MainDiv">
</div>

<img src="URL of thumbnail (e.g. smaller version)" alt="" onClick="showBig('URL of big version', 'Title')" />
```

By the way, you can ofc still add the onClicks via JS:

```
document.getElementById("yourImg").onclick = showBig('URL of Big', 'Title');
```

By the way, Don't use the same img for the thumbnails.
You'll probably use some big images which takes longer to load and then display it much smaller via CSS.
Make a smaller version (e.g. 100x100px or whatever size the thumbs should be) and only load the bigger version when the onClick is called.

Also, you better use a CSS-class like .thumbs to style the thumbs.
Otherwise you'll have to add a new ID to the list in your CSS file everytime you add a new image.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ffCtG/1/)

Answer (score 0):

My implementation gets the text from the attribute alt(could be title) I think this way can be more elegant

```
     document.getElementById('textSubtitle').innerHTML = this.alt;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/WKfc5/

Answer (score 0):

If you are okay with using jQuery, here is something that I made up real quick. I hope it is useful. [[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DQ2t9/)]

**HTML**

```
<div id="gallery">
    <div class="preview">
        <img class="previewImg" src="http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0176/5914/files/Kaylee_Radzyminski.jpg?7297" alt="" title="" />
        <div class="previewText"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="thumbnails">
        <a href="javascript: void(0);">
            <img  src="http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0176/5914/files/Kaylee_Radzyminski.jpg?7297" alt="" title="Image 1" />
        </a>
        <a href="javascript: void(0);">
            <img  src="http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0176/5914/files/Mason_Hunter_Thornal.jpg?7297" alt="" title="Image 2" />
        </a>
        <a href="javascript: void(0);">
            <img  src="http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0176/5914/files/Joseph_Nunez_4afb23ac-d71e-42a0-9366-ac78d65deaf4.jpg?7297" alt="" title="Image 3" />
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#gallery {
    overflow: hidden;
}
#gallery .preview {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}
#gallery .previewImg {}
#gallery .previewText {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100px;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
    color: #fff;
    font: normal 12px arial;
    padding: 10px;
}
#gallery .thumbnails {
    float: left;
    width:100px;
}
#gallery .thumbnails a, #gallery .thumbnails img {
    display: block;
}
#gallery .thumbnails a img {
    width: 100%;
    opacity: .5; /* css standard */
    filter: alpha(opacity=50); /* internet explorer */
}
#gallery .thumbnails a:hover img {
    opacity: 1; /* css standard */
    filter: alpha(opacity=100); /* internet explorer */
}
```

**JS**

```
$(function(){
    var gallery = $("#gallery"),
        thumbnails = gallery.find(".thumbnails a"),
        previewImg = gallery.find(".previewImg"),
        previewText = gallery.find(".previewText");

    thumbnails.on("click", function(e){
        var thumbImg = $(this).find("img");
        previewImg.attr("src", thumbImg[0].src);
        previewText.html(thumbImg[0].title);
    });
});
```